# rails equivalent of sql 'in ' operator

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

let's say that we have models, A, B, and C

A is 1:N to B

B is 1:N to C

How would I use a query to return the subset of C such that the owner of each C is one of the Bs owned by A?

essentially [How to specify multiple values in where with AR query interface in rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035365/how-to-specify-multiple-values-in-where-with-ar-query-interface-in-rails3) but that's unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a :through association:

A has_one C, :through => B

and then you would be able to do A.C

Comment: Thanks but what I mean is this:
lets say we have an array of ids. How can I use that array of ids in a where query in rails?

Comment: If model is User, User.where(:id => [1,2])

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea I could do that. I'll check mark you after the 5 minutes are up :)